# Custom deleting model and associated model via OneToOneField

Tags: django, django-admin

I'm over-writing Django's `delete_selected` admin action. I have a model (`Person`) associated to another model (`Party`) via a OneToOneField, and `delete_selected` only deletes the original model and not the data from the associated model, leaving me with "ghost rows" in my database. Seems like this in itself might indicate problems in my code, as my assumption would be that a `delete()` function would cascade delete the associated model as well.

Anyway, trouble is, my custom `delete()` function deletes `Party` first and then `Person`'s OneToOneField is blank and throws an error. Ideas?

Here's my model:

```
class Party(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    ...

class Person(models.Model):
    party = models.OneToOneField(Party, editable=False)
    firstName=models.CharField(max_length=60)
    lastName=models.CharField(max_length=60)

    def delete(self):
        self.party.delete()
        self.delete()
```

My admin:

```
class PersonAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    actions=['really_delete_selected']

    def get_actions(self, request):
        actions = super(PersonAdmin, self).get_actions(request)
        del actions['delete_selected']
        return actions

    def really_delete_selected(self, request, queryset):
        for obj in queryset:
            obj.delete()

        if queryset.count() == 1:
            message_bit = "1 person was"
        else:
            message_bit = "%s people were" % queryset.count()
        self.message_user(request, "%s successfully deleted." % message_bit)
    really_delete_selected.short_description = "Delete selected entries"
    ...
```

The error:

```
AssertionError at /admin/common/person/ 
Party object can't be deleted because its id attribute is set to None.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure why this works, but it does...

I changed my model's `delete()` function to:

```
def delete(self):
    d = self.party.id
    Party.objects.get(id__exact=d).delete()
```

I guess this is essentially doing what @Furbeenator suggested, in that by deleting the correct row in Party, that cascad deleted the correct row in Person as well. Three cheers for random shots in the dark that sometimes work, eh?

Comment: Very nice! This is definitely an interesting situation.

Answer (score 0):

Python uses indentation for its semantics analysis. Your `def delete(self):` is not properly indented, therefore it is not overriding the native delete() method. It should be under the class Person's indention level. Like this:

```
class Party(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    ...

class Person(models.Model):
    party = models.OneToOneField(Party, editable=False)
    firstName=models.CharField(max_length=60)
    lastName=models.CharField(max_length=60)

    def delete(self):
        self.party.delete()
        self.delete()
```

The same is true of your admin section, it should be indented as such:

```
class PersonAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    actions=['really_delete_selected']

    def get_actions(self, request):
        actions = super(PersonAdmin, self).get_actions(request)
        del actions['delete_selected']
        return actions

    def really_delete_selected(self, request, queryset):
        for obj in queryset:
            obj.delete()

        if queryset.count() == 1:
            message_bit = "1 person was"
        else:
            message_bit = "%s people were" % queryset.count()

        self.message_user(request, "%s successfully deleted." % message_bit)
        really_delete_selected.short_description = "Delete selected entries"
        ...
```

Comment: Sorry @Furbeenator, that's a result of StackOverflow not copying my tabs well. It's fixed now. The original code still gives me errors.

Comment: Sorry reK1NDLE. What I would suggest, is to create the Admin on the Party object instead of the Person object. That way, when you delete selected Partys, it will delete the Person object associated with it. I think you can still view the Person details through the PartyAdmin. Would that work?

Comment: Party isn't registered in the admin because, to the user's knowledge, all the info is being stored in one place, under Person. The reason the code is written like this is because there's a model named Organization that has a `OneToOneField` with Party as well. That allowed me to not have to retype the code used in Party for Organization as well.